# OpenRefine: Is there a way to auto fill a column based on another column?

Tags: openrefine

I am working on cleaning up student data received from a series of application forms. I have about 100+ rows in which the value for "state" is blank, but the city is filled in. Since we don't deal with too many cities, it's pretty obvious what the state value should be--for example, many of the cities are "Springfield" and I know the state should be "OR."

Is there an easy way to sort of tie those together? EX. if city=Springfield, then state=OR

Obviously, doesn't have to be an if/then statement, that's just how I've been thinking of it.

This is my first day using OpenRefine, so apologies if this is really simple! I'm enjoying learning all the things it can do :)

Comment: Hello Megan, welcome to SO. I think that questions on the basic use of OpenRefine are more suited for the [Open Refine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openrefine). Here, the rules are stricter. For example, you have to show what you've tried so far to solve the problem by yourself. ;)

Comment: Hi Ettore, thanks for the heads up on the google group. I’ll check it out! Any action is should take on this question here on Stack Overflow? (Delete, etc)